# Windows equivalent of the Linux command "chmod"?

Tags: windows, linux, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to change file permissions in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/106181/program-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows)

What can I use to set/change permissions on a Windows folder than not the Windows-based solution?

There is an equivalent command to chmod on Windows enviroment? There is some Windows registry command to do that?